# Why does my TV malfunction when I plug devices into a nearby outlet?

Tags: television

Whenever I plug in my laptop or anything in my TV starts getting very glitchy and it stops the minute I unplug what was plugged in.

It only does this in the living room. It doesn't do it with the lamps, mainly only chargers like my laptop charger.

But once i plugged in a hairdryer and the TV started to glitch out really bad so I think it relies on how powerful the thing plugged in is.

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: I would look for a loose connection a backstab or wirenut at the receptacle or up stream from the Tv it may be arcing and causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Radio Frequency Interference (RFI) perhaps.

To test, try a few things.

Try running the offending appliances on an extension cord from a different circuit from the other end of the dwelling.

Try the hairdryer in residence nearby.

Try using charger further away in another room.

Comment: Yes, they make radio unintentionally. Look on the case for control certification.